# Programmatically know the java object creation rate

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there a way to get the java object creation rate programmatically?
Or, the total size of object created so far, not considering the garbage collection.

Such as

```
int size = GC.getSizeTotalObjectCreated();

// do some object creation

int size2 = GC.getSizeTotalObjectCreated();

System.out.println("TotalObjectCreated" + (size2 - size));
```

Comment: [`MemoryMXBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html), see [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398555/how-to-monitor-memory-after-major-garbage-collection-via-jmx-or-code).

Comment: Do you want the rate or do you want to measure the size? These are two different things. Rate deals w/time. I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: I meant rate. But the size is equally ok as dealing with time wouldn't be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

Using MemoryPoolMXBean heap size can be found along with the usage details of Eden/Survivor/Old Gen.

Object creation rate can be calculated on the basis of free heap size difference at given two points in time.

```
public void printHeapDetails() {        
    System.out.println("Heap size: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println("Free heap size: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());

    for (MemoryPoolMXBean bean : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
        if (bean.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP)
            System.out.printf("Name: %s: %s\n", bean.getName(),
                    bean.getUsage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not really I am looking for. If garbage collection occurring in the middle of measurement it will give wrong value.